# Interpreting rack-timeout service time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout, rack

In a Rails app I'm using `rack-timeout` set to time out requests taking longer than 30 seconds.

Strangely, there are situations where `rack-timeout` enters extremely late and the overall service time of the request can end up being up to 7-30 minutes.

Here are 3 examples to illustrate this strange situation:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's my middleware stack:

```
use Raven::Rack
use HireFire::Middleware
use ActionDispatch::SSL
use Rack::Sendfile
use HeaderDelete
use ActionDispatch::Static
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x0000000002d643e8>
use Rack::Timeout
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use LoggingMiddleware
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use Chewy::Railtie::RequestStrategy
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
...
```

Given that `rack-timeout` is positioned early in the stack, how to interpret that some requests go way beyond their limit?

I think it may be related to timeouts during IO blocks (as detailed [here](https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout/blob/master/doc/risks.md#timing-out-during-io-blocks)), though that won't explain why would the first log (`state=ready`) from `rack-timeout` come 27 minutes after H12 from Heroku router (examples 1 and 3 above)?

Can having `rack-timeout` service timeout set to 30 seconds (same as Heroku router) be a problem?

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: **Sidenote**: Rails uses DataBase connection pools. Connections are checked out and released using one of the Rails middleware. If you're killing a thread using the `Rack::Timeout` middleware, the database connection might leak (be lost) since it's never returned to the pool. This will cause your application to grind to a halt as ActionCable waits for connections even though the pool is empty and (presumably) tries to recuperate from the leak.

Comment: It could be that your server has a high backlog of requests in the Application Server's cache (puma? passenger? iodine? what server are you running?) - this might cause the H12 timeout to occur before the request is forwarded to your application.